# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved variables after they have already been freed)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, autograd

I have an issue with my function `train_model()` which stops after 1 epoch.
I try to specificy `retain_graph = True` at `loss.backward()` with no success (same error).
There is my code

```
class Activation(nn.Module) :
    def forward(self,x):
        return torch.sigmoid(4*x)+F.softplus(x) 

def train_model(model,train_input,train_target,nb_epochs = 10, lr = 5e-2):
    train_input.requires_grad = True
    loss_list=[]
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=lr)
    for epoch in range(nb_epochs):
        print(epoch)
        output = model(train_input)
        print('output shape : ',output.shape)
        print('Target shape : ',train_target.shape)
        loss = criterion(output,train_target)
        loss_list.append(loss)
        print('loss : ',loss)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        #loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print('la')
    return loss_list
    
m = 4
student_1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2,m),Activation(),nn.Linear(m,1))
student_1.to(dev)
positions.requires_grad = True
loss_output = train_model(student_1,positions,output)
```

With I have the following output :

```
0
output shape :  torch.Size([10000, 1])
Target shape :  torch.Size([10000, 1])
loss :  tensor(1.6407, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MseLossBackward>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1705345/1861791313.py in <module>
     23 student_1.to(dev)
     24 positions.requires_grad = True
---> 25 loss_output = train_model(student_1,positions,output)

/tmp/ipykernel_1705345/1861791313.py in train_model(model, train_input, train_target, nb_epochs, lr)
     13         print('loss : ',loss)
     14         optimizer.zero_grad()
---> 15         loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
     16         #loss.backward()
     17         optimizer.step()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    253                 create_graph=create_graph,
    254                 inputs=inputs)
--> 255         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    256 
    257     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    145         retain_graph = create_graph
    146 
--> 147     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    148         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    149         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved variables after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved variables after calling backward.
```

Can someone explain me how to fix this please?
Thank you.

Comment: What is `output` in `loss_output = train_model(student_1,positions,output)`?

Comment: `output` corresponds to a tensor. When I print it I have this :                                       
 ` tensor([[-0.0297],
        [-0.0047],
        [ 0.0220],
        ...,
        [ 1.0900],
        [ 1.1186],
        [ 1.1487]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>) `

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I think the error came by the fact that output  was also defined in the function

Comment: In this case, output was computed using weights that will later be updated by `optimizer.step()` . What is does `output` represent exactly, are you considering the output of the previous inference as the new target?

Comment: Not in my case, output was the target of my model and thus I have changed its name to target to have  with `loss_output = train_model(student_1,positions,target)` and now this works. Thank you a lot.